# Make excel cell equal certain value from a different cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

This should be an easy one but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  I want to change a cell's value from another cell based on an `IF` statement.

I have

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I2/J2),"K2"=I2/J2,Null)
```

This formula is in L2.  I'm trying to get K2 to be the value of I2/J2 but it's evaluating it as T/F.

How do I "remotely" set a cell value please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula needs to go into K2. You can't remotely set a value of another cell. In K2 put `=IF(ISNUMBER(I2/J2),I2/J2,Null)`

...although I'm not sure why you are testing that the result of a division is a number. It's either a number or it's an error. Perhaps `=IF(ISERROR(I2/J2),I2/J2,Null)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I was unaware of the `ISERROR()`.  You're correct that does the same thing in this scenario.  Thank you for the info!

Comment: @TKEyi60 - the [IFERROR()](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/IFERROR-function-1660eb2d-4087-4ed4-a6f9-c8e040a1d0f7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function was introduced to the Excel repertoire with Excel 2007. This shortens the formula in K2 to `=IFERROR(I2/J2, Null)`. If you do not have to provide compatibility with pre-Excel 2007 then this would be the preferred method. I'm also not sure if Null is the appropriate error controlled result; it may be better as `=IFERROR(I2/J2, "")` which would leave an empty string in the case of an error like `#DIV/0!`..